# Php foreach group items into a container

Tags: php, foreach

I can't figure out how to group my subcategories into a container after every fifth record.

for example I would like to output my subcats like this

```
<ul>
<li>
 Main category
 <div>
  <div class="subcontainer">
   sub1
   sub2
   sub3
   sub4
   sub5
  </div>
  <div class="subcontainer">
   sub6
   sub7
   sub8
   sub9
   sub10
  </div>
 </div>
</li>
</ul>
```

I tried this:

```
<?php
$i=0;
foreach ($cat->sub as $child) {
  if($i % 5 == 0){
   echo '<div class="subcontainer"><div>'.$child->name.'</div></div>';
  } $i++;
}
?>
```

But this will output only the 5th elements in the array.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to always print your `$child->name` variable and on every 5th item also print the `</div><div>` part.  You almost have it.

```
$i=0;
echo '<div class="subcontainer">';
foreach($cat->sub as $child) {
    $i++;
    echo $child->name; // I'm assuming this is what contains your "sub1"-"sub10"
    if ($i % 5 == 0) {
        echo '</div><div class="subcontainer">';
    }
}
echo '</div>';
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also get `$i`with `foreach ($cat->sub as $i=>$child)`

Comment: Not necessarily - you're making an assumption of how the asker's array is indexed.